# Gson return null for the nested-object

Tags: java, json, gson

Actually, I try to implement so basic thing on my code. I have a json file. Then I want to read this json file and convert it to a Java object. To handle it, I used gson but somehow it returns null for nested-object.

Json:

```
{
  "results": {
    "ads-result": {
      "data": [
        {
          "id": "1"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

TestJson:

```
@Getter
public class TestJson
{
    private ResultsData results;

    @Getter
    public static class ResultsData
    {
        @JsonProperty(value = "ads-result")
        private AdsResultData adsResult;
    }

    @Getter
    public static class AdsResultData
    {
        private List<AdApp> data;
    }

    @Getter
    public static class AdApp
    {
        private long id;
    }
}
```

and finally I try to read it from the json file:

```
public static TestJson getDefaultAdResult() throws Exception
{
    String json = IOUtils.toString(
            getResourceAsStream("test.json"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    return new Gson().fromJson(json, TestJson.class);
}
```

But at the end of it, when I try to reach the `System.out.println(resultJson.getResults().getAdsResult());` it gives null. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing Jackson and Gson annotations.

Make this change:

```
// @JsonProperty(value = "ads-result") - Jackson
@SerializedName("ads-result") // Gson
private AdsResultData adsResult;
```